# proving the series converges as well as finding its limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

We have a series defined as:

$a_0 = 1$ and $a_n = \sqrt{2 + a_{n-1}}$.

The way I approached is as follows:

as $n$ tends to $\infty$  we can write:

$a_{\infty} = L$

$L= \sqrt{2 + L}$

Then:

$L^2 - L - 2 = 0$

Which yields:

$$L = 2$$ as the desired limit.

Is this right, or do I need to prove the existence  of the limit before doing this?

Comment: Yes, you have to show the limit, in fact, exists. (And mention why $L$ can't be $-1$.)

Comment: how would you go about it? 
Sorry, but I've just started learning series.

Comment: Try showing that the sequence (not series) is monotone and bounded.

Comment: Don't forget that $L=-1$ is another possibility until you've shown that the sequence is monotone and bounded.